# How to fix "Failed to load resource" bug when submit form to download file?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, download

I try to create some script to send a lot of required data to the server after that server will send a generated file back. I know, it's possible to create some link that contain my data like the following code for sending data to server and get the file back.

```
<a href="domain.com/getExcel.aspx?id=ABC&title=Report1" target="_blank" />
```

But the maximum length of URL is around 2000 characters that I cannot guarantee the length of data will not over this limit. So I try to use ["jQuery Plugin for Requesting Ajax-like File Downloads"](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/) to send data to the server by dynamic creating form with hidden input.

Everything works great on IE9. But I got **"Failed to load resource"** error message when I use it in Google Chrome 9. I think this problem occurs only when response header is set to Attachment.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/SP3Tx/3/show/

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/SP3Tx/3/

Do you have any walk-around to fix this bug?

**Update**

I just submit this bug to chromium issue tracker.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75384

Comment: Just to inform that this bug seems to not be present in 10.0.648.133 beta.

Comment: I just try my demo page on Google Chrome 10.0.648.134 (stable) but I still saw this bug.

POST http://www.opendrive.com/files/17416342_3M6ke_2218/TestFile.txt undefined (undefined)